# How do I activate/deactivate CSS on button click?

Tags: css, wordpress

My website is: http://test.highfieldscentre.ac.uk/wordpress/

I'm trying to add an accessibility feature to it which enables visitors to click a button to "turn on" and "turn off" a high contrast mode (i.e. black background with yellow text). I have the CSS for this, but I'm not sure how to make it so it can be turned on and off.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct answer but you can achieve this with Jquery , use click() function then add or remove class with addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: This can't be done with just CSS alone, and have it persist across pages. You can use JS to use local storage to save the value and then apply styles accordingly on page load, you could also use a back-end programming language to create a cookie and store that, then apply styles based on that cookie.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach may be to use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` function to append a class to your `body` as in the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc2z4hj3/

Here we have an element that on click toggles the `contrast` class on and off.  From there you can modify your CSS as needed to provide the standard/high contrast options.

An example of the necessary jQuery is on the Fiddle and below:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggleContrast").click(function() {
       $('body').toggleClass('contrast');
  })
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'm still confused as to where the jQuery needs to go? Can you explain in more detail please how to implement this?

Comment: Typically you would insert this sort of script above the `</body>` of your code.  If you are completely unfamiliar with how to implement jQuery on your website, I would recommend you begin researching jQuery tutorials.  StackOverflow recently implemented a Documentation service that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/211/getting-started-with-jquery#t=201607281504293072047

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JQuery Click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/) in jQuery to [add a class](https://api.jquery.com/addClass) or [remove a class.](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass)

Comment: How/where to I use jQuery? Does it go into the CSS file? I've not got any experience with that...

Comment: No you have to use jQuery in javascript based tags e.g <script type="text/javascript"></script>. If you click on the links provided above, they will show examples of a html page with each function being used.

Comment: jQuery isn't required for something that simple.

Comment: @EmmanuelB - True, but consider the OP.  This is for a WordPress installation, so jQuery is already present... so why not use it.

Comment: @RobertC True thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have only one CSS file, to reach better performances. You could simply add a class on body, like "contrast", and define some specific case for elements within the page when the class is here.

Then you can just switch the class with JS.

```js
var contrastSwitcher = document.querySelector('.contrast-switch'),
 body = document.querySelector('body');

contrastSwitcher.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('contrast') !== null) {
   localStorage.removeItem('contrast');
    body.classList.remove('contrast');
  }
  else {
    localStorage.setItem('contrast', true);
    body.classList.add('contrast');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #5d90c4;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: .6em 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: 0;
}

.contrast .btn {
  background: #222;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn contrast-switch">Click me !</button>
```

This way, using localStorage, it remember the user setting.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above this is accomplished using jQuery.

On a very simplified, fundamental level the internet consists of three "languages" - HTML, CSS and JavaScript (I will be getting to jQuery in just a short while!).

All of these three have a special purpose to the webpage. Imagine that you're building a house:

- **HTML** would be the basic building blocks, basically the walls and the
  roof. HTML is the structure of the website.
- **CSS** would be the colour of the house, maybe the materials used,
  all of the "designy" stuff. CSS is the look of the website.
- **JavaScript** would be all of the wiring and plumbing in the house, the
  stuff that tells the lightbulb to turn on when you press the switch. JavaScript is the functionality and interactivity of the website.

Pure JavaScript can be tedious to work with at times, requiring a lot of code to do simple tasks. jQuery was invented so that you could (citing their slogan here) *Write less, do more*. It's basically a lot of prewritten JavaScript functions that you can import to your site and then use.

I would recommend checking out the jQuery course at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/), its free, short, effective and will get you going really quickly, but most importantly give you an understanding of how to solve not only this problem but many others to come as well! :)